# long sequence of satellites moving west to east?

Tags: artificial-satellite

yesterday (27/3/2020), 20:00, I was on high ground in central switzerland and looked south. in the clear night sky, I saw what I think could have been satellites: linear trajectory, high speed, fainter than appearing stars, no blinking.

however, there were a lot of objects; a whole sequence of equidistant points that kept going for as long as I looked (5-10 minutes, and they were all seemingly following the same trajectory.

can anyone tell me what I saw?

Comment: I just saw them moving west to east here west of Vancouver Canada about 21.25 PDT following roughly 49 parallel trajectory. Almost all spaced equally. More than 20 for sure.
Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpaceX has been launching Starlink satellites in large quantities and a recent launch may be the satellites you've seen. On release they have close spacing and slowly separate to the appropriate orbits.

According to the website, [Heavens-Above](https://www.heavens-above.com/starlink.aspx), the most recent launch was Starlink 5 on 18 March 2020. The site describes the visible satellites as "string of pearls."

Comment: They can also be as bright as Rigel, even at 15 deg visual separation, and flash brighter than Venus for a second while they rise from the West (if the orientations are right), and the show can last an hour.  Look for occasional side-by-side instead of single file.  If they stay this bright after the whole system is up, we'll all be dizzy!

Comment: yupp they were pretty bright and indeed some were flying side by side along the trajectory